# Handle validation errors on ajax form before resolving?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

I have a page that submits 2 different users/members forms to add them in a group and then uses stripe to pay for the memberships.

I want to make sure that if there are validation errors on the first user that the validation errors get handled before the second user form tries to post, and likewise with the second user before the payment is processed.

I created a function to submit a form with ajax and it has certain checks. I makes sure the form is present and not disabled. I tried checking if errors are present here, so they could be fixed before proceeding, but it doesn't work. I then posts data via ajax. In the resolved/done state is currently when it grabs validation error from the response and passes them to the form via another function. Here is the submit forms function:

```
function submitFormAjax(data) {
    if (data.length && $('.error-message').length === 0) {
        var formId = data.attr('id');
        if ( $('#'+formId ).hasClass('disabled') ) {
            console.log('form is disabled don\'t post data');
        } else {
            return $.ajax({
                type: data.attr('method'),
                url: data.attr('action'),
                data: data.serialize(),
                beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                }
            })
            .done( function( response ) {
                addFormErrors(formId, response);
            })
            .fail(function( response ) {
                console.log( response );
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I would ideally like to be able to handle these validation errors before the form's state is considered resolved/done so that the users get added in order. I need them in order so that the primary(first user) account is added first and then the second user can be associated or grouped to that user.

I am using a promise type chain and also tried to check for validation errors here before posting, but also to no avail.

Here is the promise chain function:

```
function submitAllForms() {
    // wait until both of the other forms' data are submitted
    $.when( 
        function() {
            if ($('.error-message').length) {
                alert('Waiting for validation errors to be fixed.');
            } else {
                submitFormAjax($('#userForm'));
            }
        }, 
        function() {
            if ($('.error-message').length) {
                alert('Waiting for validation errors to be fixed.');
            } else {
                submitFormAjax($('#secondUserForm'));
            }
        }).then(
        function() {
            if ( $('.error-message').length ) {
                $form.find('button').prop('disabled', false);
            } else {
                $('#payment-form').get(0).submit();
            }
    });
}
```

Comment: Your anonymous functions don't return any promise and so `$.when()` treating them as resolved without waiting for any async response. You should set `return submitFormAjax($('#userForm'));` & `return submitFormAjax($('#secondUserForm'));`  where `submitFormAjax();` return a promise/ajax request (alrerady the case here). BTW, you should set your check `if ($('.error-message').length)` inside `submitFormAjax()`. And so your code could be: `$.when(submitFormAjax($('#userForm')), submitFormAjax($('#secondUserForm'))).then(...);`

Comment: @A.Wolff So I tried checking for $('.error-message').length inside the submitFormAjax() as it shows in the code above, but to no avail. I have also tried it with the submitAllForms() function the exact way you have the $.when().then() functions. It actually just posts everything as if the state is resolved. Do I need to check for .error-message somewhere else? Or is there a way to return the promise in a pending state so it doesn't just process everything?

Comment: @A.Wolff It seems like I need to make this synchronous since user #2 shouldn't be added unless user #1 has already been added, correct? But, everywhere I am reading says that async: false is deprecated and we shouldn't use it. Is there a way to make sure the first user gets added before the second?

Comment: If you want to keep async requests sequential, then don't use `$.when`: `submitFormAjax($('#userForm')).then(submitFormAjax.bind(this, $('#secondUserForm'))).then(...);`. That's said, you could rewrite your function to handle sequential request, serach for: `ajax sequential requests` or something like that.